# When should I restart R session, GUI or computer?

Tags: r, rstudio, rcpp

I use R, Rstudio and Rcpp and I spent over a week debugging some code, that was just giving errors and warnings in unexpected places, in some cases with direct sample code from online or package documentation.

I often restart the R session or Rstudio if there are obvious problems and they usually go away.
But this morning it was really bad to the point were basic R commands would fail and restarting R did nothing. I closed all the Rstudio sessions and restarted the machine for good measure, (which was unnecessary).

When it came back and I re-loaded the sessions everything seems to be working.
Even the some rcpp code I was working on for weeks with outside packages will now compile and run where it gave gibberish errors before.

I have known for a while that R needs to be restarted once in a while, but I know it when basic functions don't run, how can I know earlier.

I am looking for a good general resource or function that can tell me I need to restart because something is not running right. I would be nice if I can also know what to restart.
Whether the R session, the GUI such as Rstudio, all sessions and GUIs or a full machine restart.

Comment: When shits broken that's when you try turning it off and on again. I'm not sure what other advise you'll get on the topic.

Comment: @Dason: Well put. I think a certain development package implied you could do it all from the R prompt...

Comment: More interesting is when everything you had before is working, but if you try loading something new like a package or function then it fails. How can I know that is is failing from a real error or the shits is broken. Thank you.

Comment: Changing interface can do that to you, both for compiled and even interpreted code.

Answer (score 3):

For as long as I have been dabbling with or actually using R (ie more than two decades), it has *always* been recommended to start a clean and fresh session.

Which is why I prefer to work on command-line for tests. When you invoke `R`, or `Rscript`, or, in my case, `r` (from [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html)) you *know* you get a fresh session free of possible side-effects. By keeping these tests to the command-line, my main sessions (often multiple instances inside Emacs via ESS, possibly multiple RStudio sessions too) are less affected.

Even RStudio defaults to 'install and restart' when you rebuild a package.

(I will note that a certain development package implies you could cleanly unload a package. That has been debated at length, and I think by now even its authors qualify that claim. I don't really know or case as I don't use it, having had established workflows before it appeared.)

And to add: You almost never need to restart the computer.  But a fresh clean process is a something to use often. Your computer can create millions of those for you.

Comment: I always use install and restart, but it seems even that fails so a full restart of everything is needed. The question is how do you know. Thank you.

Comment: Just avoid the question and work on the command-line _for the test evaluations_ ie when building / testing / debugging a package.

Comment: The command-line fails as well. I think it is because packages or dlls may be loaded elsewhere so they cannot be updated or loaded. But still is there a time you can say for sure that you need to restart. Thanks again.

Comment: Ahh, now we are getting closer to an actuall Rcpp question.  Sometimes you need to rebuild.  Not always.  But if something is funky, it does not hurt.

Comment: One of the really bad R defaults is to reload the workspace when you start a new R session.  When I teach R programming, one of the very first things I do is to tell people how to turn off this awful choice.  But by default, restarting R doesn't give you a clean session.  Grrr.

Comment: Of course it does:  `q()` always ask, you can always say "No".

Comment: Too late.  I already called `rnorm(1); q()` and answered "yes" before you told me that.  Now I'm condemned to get the same random numbers for the rest of time, because when I was ignorant I saved `.Random.seed`.

Comment: @user2554330 I recommend you remove that comment.

Comment: It also just plain wrong as you can convince yourself with two or three quick `Rscript` calls.  R is smarter that you think it is.

Comment: Dason and Dirk, I was exaggerating, and I know how to fix the stuck `.Random.seed`.  But I still contend that the reloading of the workspace is a bad default, especially if you say "No" to `q()` almost every time but not every time.